# What does the subset with slash symbol mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does the following mean:

$\nsubseteq$

I cant find any definition for it?

---

*Previous editor's note:*  I replaced a linked image with the $\nsubseteq$ symbol to make the question self-contained.  I am pointing this out here to avoid comments/questions such as, "You don't know what it means but you know how to write it in $\mathrm\TeX$?"

Comment: "is not a subset of"

Comment: Is not a subset of

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, $\not\subseteq$ means "not subset of." Hence, $A\not\subseteq B$ means that $A$ is *not* a subset of $B$.

All the more to make this clear, that symbol is easily typeset with `\not\subseteq`.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a subset of. If $A \nsubseteq B$, it means that $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: Is there any distinction between $\not\subseteq$ and $\not\subset$?

Comment: @RobertSoupe I'm not sure, but if I were to guess I would say that that would mean not a strict subset of, i.e. that $A\not\subseteq B$ disallows $A=B$ but $A\not\subset B$ allows it.

Answer (score 0):

If A ⊈ B, then no member of A is a member of B.

The symbol '⊈' represent the negation of the relation of **improper inclusion**, '⊆'. A ⊆ B if and only if all member of A is a member of B or if A = B.

Must be distinguished from the negation of the proper inclusion '⊂'. 'A ⊂ B' says that all member of A are members of B, but is not the case that A = B.

Thereby, for example, A ⊆ A, but is not the case that A ⊂ A.